# Oracle In-memory population

Tags: oracle, in-memory

I've just started my experience with Oracle In Memory (in a single-instance database).
I've activated this feature and that's my parameters

```
select * from v$parameter where name like '%inme%'
    inmemory_clause_default 2   NO INMEMORY
    inmemory_force  2   DEFAULT
    inmemory_max_populate_servers   3   9
    inmemory_query  2   ENABLE
    inmemory_size   6   5368709120
    inmemory_trickle_repopulate_servers_percent 3   25
    optimizer_inmemory_aware    1   TRUE
```

I've activated the in-memory storage for my table

```
alter table dwh.account_dh 
INMEMORY MEMCOMPRESS FOR CAPACITY HIGH PRIORITY CRITICAL NO DUPLICATE
INMEMORY MEMCOMPRESS FOR CAPACITY HIGH(branchid,currencyid,corraccountid,account2id,clientid,attributevhd,
dateopen,dateclose,openingreason,ownertype,accounttype,krv_type,symincconid,
overestsign,figroup,accountparentid,ficoef,managaccountid,parentid,
profitcenterid,intercompanybranchid,accountgroupid,budgetportfolioid,
managmentfiid,bankproductid,acclevel,datematurity,payingagentacc,
operofficebranchid,respemployeeid,datebegin,dateend,closereason,
datasourceid,rowstatus,isforexreval,add_primarysource,loadid,nextloadid,
add_clienttype,add_retailsource,add_okatoid,vip)
INMEMORY  NO MEMCOMPRESS(id,accountnumber,accountname,externalid,rid,add_primaryid);
```

Then I've made a full scan on the table

```
select /*+ FULL(T) NO_PARALLEL */ COUNT(*) FROM DWH.account_dh T;
```

And I see the following

```
select owner,segment_name,partition_name,inmemory_size,bytes,
bytes_not_populated,populate_status from v$im_segments order by bytes desc;
OWNER SEGMENT_NAME PARTITION_NAME INMEMORY_SIZE BYTES     BYTES_NOT_POPULATED POPULATE_STATUS
DWH   ACCOUNT_DH   PMAX           9568256       292552704 268648448 COMPLETED
DWH   ACCOUNT_DH   P1             24248320       58720256         0 COMPLETED
```

In the same time my inmemory area is not filled completely

```
select * from V$INMEMORY_AREA;
POOL      ALLOC_BYTES USED_BYTES POPULATE_STATUS CON_ID
1MB POOL  4293918720  132120576   DONE             0
64KB POOL 1056964608    3014656   DONE             0
```

Why the population is finished but there are non zero not populated bytes?